# Vue watch array in array

Tags: vue.js

Hi I needed to indicate which field was touched. I found solution,

```
const form = useForm('post', route('dashboard.purchases.store'), {
    seller_id: 0,
    info_array: [{ title_id: 0, price_usd: '', price_gel: '', quantity: '' }]
})
let touchedFields = new Set();

watch(() => form.data(), (newData, oldData) => {
    let changedFields = Object.keys(newData).filter(field => newData[field] !== oldData);
    touchedFields = new Set([...changedFields, ...touchedFields]);
    console.log(touchedFields);
},{deep: true})
```

But its indicates when seller_id is changed. Can someone help me to do same with info_array

Comment: It's unknown what's useForm and how it works. You can possibly watch on form.data().info_array or whatever data is in your case

Comment: Did you tried this ?

`let changedFields = Object.keys(newData).filter(field => {
 return (typeof newData[field] === 'object') ? JSON.stringify(newData[field]) !== JSON.stringify(oldData[field]) : newData[field] !== oldData[field]
});`